# Docker swarm worker service unable to access service on manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a single node docker Swarm. I deployed a stack with Influxdb (placement: manager), Grafana (placement: manager) and cAdvisor (deploy mode global).

I use Portainer to visualize the stack. And it correctly shows 1 manager node with its services.

Then I added a second (worker) node with `docker swarm join etc...`

Now the cAdvisor service is also launched on the worker, but it has a problem, it keeps logging:

`E1115 14:52:46.772290       1 memory.go:91] failed to write stats to influxDb - Post http://influx:8086/write?consistency=&db=cadvisor&precision=&rp=: dial tcp: lookup influx on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host`

Any ideas?

Thanx

Comment: Did you open the required ports for communication between the manager and workers? https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts

Comment: Yes. And I created an overlay network (of course). Services are all attached to same network